# Vaadin Push Exception when logging out (Vaadin-Springboot)

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, logout, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin(14.6.4) Springboot (2.5.2) application using `PushMode.MANUAL`. When logging out of the application, the PushAtmosphereHandler throws a push exception:

```
2021-06-29 08:39:35.860 ERROR 25843 --- [      Atmosphere-Shared-2] PushAtmosphereHandler               : Exception in push connection

java.io.IOException: Connection remotely closed for d7e35c49-ce28-4d49-9b48-eed7d3865f4a
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:230) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:220) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.WebSocket.write(WebSocket.java:46) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResponseImpl$Stream.write(AtmosphereResponseImpl.java:957) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.handler.AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(AbstractReflectorAtmosphereHandler.java:155) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onStateChange(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:54) ~[flow-server-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.invokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1037) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.prepareInvokeOnStateChange(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1057) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.executeAsyncWrite(DefaultBroadcaster.java:871) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster$2.run(DefaultBroadcaster.java:474) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1.jar!/:2.4.30.slf4jvaadin1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
```

Is there anything one can do to prevent this exception to be thrown?

I recently upgraded from Vaadin 14.5.x to 14.6.4 and from Springboot 2.4.x to 2.5.2. The exception did not happen with the "old" versions.

Comment: Looks like you "loose" the user session on logout, so there is no associated UI anymore. Perhapts just check if the UI still exists before doing pushes?

Comment: The exception happens when the user logs-off (url /logout). So the loss of the session is expected. I am not sure what causes the "push" at this occasion.